# PopViewController in Tabbar application

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am working on a Tab-bar application.

```
                           TAB-BAR CONTROLLER
                                   |
          _______________________________________________________
         |                |                 |                  |

       View 1           View 2            View 3            View 4
        |                 |
     SearchingON       Detail View
```

Problem 1 :I have a button (Let say Sign Out), On click of The button which is on View 4, I want to pop the Detail view of View 2.

So that after new login new user should not reach to detail veiw.

I have tried :

```
 if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"IsChattingON"])
 {
    ChatDetail *chat = [[ChatDetail alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChatDetail" bundle:nil];

    [chat BackButtonClicked:nil];
 }
```

and in Detail View back Button my code is :

```
-(IBAction)BackButtonClicked:(id)sender
{

 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"IsChattingON"];

 [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Here User Defaults having Bool value whether Detail View is open or not.

Problem 2 : I am applying Search on View 1's Table View and want to remove Search if View 4 SignOut button is clicked. I want to refresh my View 1 if Signout button of View 4 is clicked.

For removing Search I have done this code but not getting the desired results.

```
 PeopleController *People = [[PeopleController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PeopleController" bundle:nil];

 People.isSearchingRecords = NO;
```

I have Searched so far about popViewControllers but cant find this scene. Pls let me know  how can I achieve this functionality.

Comment: do u wan't to show the root screen for any tab when clicked? no matter what was last state

Comment: +1, Nice and Tough Question this time :P.. remember me?..

Comment: Fine, great... so enjoying iPhone Development or not.??

Answer (score 0):

You should not allocate a new view controller when the user taps on logout,
instead you should do the following

```
- (void) logOut
{
   //get the view 2
   //you should have a way to access view 2

   [view2 closeChatView];
}

//On view 2 maintain a reference of chat detail controller
- (void) closeChatView
{
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"IsChattingON"];

   //chat is the reference to the chat details controller
   [chat.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Actually I have Custom Tab-bar, and i cant find any way to access view 2 , what should i do ??

Comment: Custom tab-bar, you should create a property of NSMutableArray *views;  and create a property around it, this will hold all the views in the custom-tab bar, then access view number two [tabbar.views objectAtIndex:1];

Comment: Also there are other ways, easier ways, you could register a notification listener in the view2 class, and when logout is pressed post a notification to view2, this way you will not need to know view 2, for further reading about notifications check this tutorial http://iphonebyradix.blogspot.com/2011/07/nsnotificationcenter-tutorial.html ,  please dont forget to accept the answer if it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you keep instance of navigation controllers in appDelegate then you can try this:

```
NSArray *viewNavStack = appDelegate.viewNavController.viewControllers;
    if ([viewNavStack count] > 1) {
        [appDelegate.overviewNavController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got solution for Problem 2 :

I am setting a NSUserDefault BOOL to NO, and in ViewWillAppear I am getting that UserDefaults value whether searching is ON or not.

On click of Signout Button :

```
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:NO forKey:@"SearchingON"];
```

and on View 1 :

```
       isSearchingRecords = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey: @"SearchingON"];

    if (isSearchingRecords)
    {
        self.btnSearchCancel.hidden = NO;
    }else
    {
        self.btnSearchCancel.hidden = YES;
    }
```

But cant find the solution of Problem 1 - to pop the view by another tab, if any one have any idea pls let me know !!